# Value of array elements is different in caller and callee

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, multidimensional-array

I have a function that passes a 2d array as an argument to another function. 2d array is passed as int**.

Caller Function:

```
bool isMatch(string s, string p)
{
    int **dp;
    int* a[s.size()];
    dp = a;
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        int b[p.size()];
        dp[i] = b;
    }
    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<p.size();j++)
        {
            dp[i][j] = -1;
        }
    }
    cout<<dp[0][0]<<endl;
    return test(s,p,dp);
}
```

Calle Function:

```
bool test(string s,string p,int **dp)
{
    cout<<dp[0][0]<<endl;
    return true;
}
```

Now when i print dp[0][0] in isMatch() function -1 is printed which is the expected value. But when i pass the 2d array to an another function (ie; test()) and print dp[0][0] i get random values like 950192880, 337836240 etc. Why is this happenning eventhough everything passed by reference and the stack is not cleared until the caller function is exited?

Comment: you need to post a [mcve]. It is unclear how `cout<<dp[i][j]<<endl;` is supposed to compile when neither `i` nor `j` are declared

Comment: `dp[i] = b;` -- `b` dies on the very next line, at the end of its scope.

Comment: please do not make up some fantasy code to post here. Instead make sure the code you post really does procude the output you claim.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to change i and j while posting i have updated the code now

Comment: @Quentin Thanks!! Didnt think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

array `b` is declared in `for` loop, so it's invalid out of the loop. you said that the output of `dp` is as expected, but it's by chance. you should allocated `b` using `new`.